# What's meaning of plt.plot(x[0:-1],y/y[0])?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting an exponential distribution using the information provided by the tutor.

```
plt.plot(x[:-1],y/y[0])
plt.plot(tvals,pvals)
plt.show()
```

But, I do not know what's meaning of x[:-1] and y/y[0]?

Comment: Choose all but the last element of x, and divide (normalize) y by its first element.

Comment: Is there anything specific you don't understand?

Comment: You may want to read up on Python list indexing. This is basic Python knowledge.

Comment: What is the type of `y`?

Comment: Here is a link to the official documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=list%20slices#lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x[:-1] means all the elements except the last one

y/y[0] is simply dividing the array y by the first value i.e y[0] of the array.

**Code Example**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
y = np.array([2, 4, 6])

a = x[:-1]  # [1, 3, 5]
b = y/y[0]  # [1, 2, 3]

plt.plot(a, b)
```

**Output**

[image: Output]